# Chakra ui - page shell - how to populate the page based on sidebar menu

Tags: reactjs, chakra-ui

I'm trying to figure out how to use the [Chakra UI page shell](https://pro.chakra-ui.com/components/application/shells), so that I can add components to render in the main segment of the shell, for each sidebar menu item.

The sidebar menu has NavButton items as follows:

```
              <NavButton label="Settings" />
```

I'm trying to find a way to add a component (say, Settings) which has the content to render in the main segment of the shell.

How can I do that?

The full dashboard is as follows:

```
import {
    // As,
    Avatar,
    Box,
    BoxProps,
    Button,
    ButtonProps,
    chakra, 
    Container,
    Divider, 
    Drawer,
    DrawerContent,
    DrawerOverlay,
    Flex,
    Heading,
    HStack,
    Icon,
    Input,
    InputLeftElement,
    InputGroup,
    // Progress, 
    // SimpleGrid,
    Stack,
    Text,
    useBreakpointValue,
    useColorModeValue,
    useDisclosure,
    IconButton, 
    IconButtonProps
  } from '@chakra-ui/react'
  import * as React from 'react'
  import { FiDownloadCloud } from 'react-icons/fi'
  // import { CgWorkAlt } from 'react-icons/cg'
  
  import {
    // FiBarChart2,
    // FiBookmark,
    // FiCheckSquare,
    // FiHelpCircle,
    // FiHome,
    FiSearch,
    // FiSettings
  } from 'react-icons/fi'
  
const Card = (props: BoxProps) => (
    <Box
      minH="3xs"
      bg="bg-surface"
      boxShadow={useColorModeValue('sm', 'sm-dark')}
      borderRadius="lg"
      {...props}
    />
  )  

  const Bar = chakra('span', {
    baseStyle: {
      display: 'block',
      pos: 'absolute',
      w: '1.25rem',
      h: '0.125rem',
      rounded: 'full',
      bg: 'currentcolor',
      mx: 'auto',
      insetStart: '0.125rem',
      transition: 'all 0.12s',
    },
  })

  const ToggleIcon = (props: { active: boolean }) => {
    const { active } = props
    return (
      <Box
        className="group"
        data-active={active ? '' : undefined}
        as="span"
        display="block"
        w="1.5rem"
        h="1.5rem"
        pos="relative"
        aria-hidden
        pointerEvents="none"
      >
        <Bar top="0.4375rem" _groupActive={{ top: '0.6875rem', transform: 'rotate(45deg)' }} />
        <Bar bottom="0.4375rem" _groupActive={{ bottom: '0.6875rem', transform: 'rotate(-45deg)' }} />
      </Box>
    )
  }
  
  interface ToggleButtonProps extends IconButtonProps {
    isOpen: boolean
  }
  
  const ToggleButton = (props: ToggleButtonProps) => {
    const { isOpen, ...iconButtonProps } = props
    return (
      <IconButton
        position="relative"
        variant="unstyled"
        size="sm"
        color={isOpen ? 'white' : 'muted'}
        zIndex="skipLink"
        icon={<ToggleIcon active={isOpen} />}
        {...iconButtonProps}
      />
    )
  }

  interface UserProfileProps {
    name: string
    // image: string
    title: string
  }

  const UserProfile = (props: UserProfileProps) => {
    const { name, title } = props
    return (
      <HStack spacing="3" ps="2">
        <Avatar name={name} boxSize="10" />
        <Box>
          <Text fontWeight="medium" fontSize="sm">
            {name}
          </Text>
          <Text color="muted" fontSize="sm">
            {title}
          </Text>
        </Box>
      </HStack>
    )
  }  

const Sidebar = () => (
    <Flex as="section" minH="100vh" bg="bg-canvas" maxW="100%" p="0">
      <Flex
        flex="1"
        bg="brand.white"
        // overflowY="auto"
        maxW="100%" p="0"
        // maxW={{ base: 'full', sm: 'xs' }}
        py={{ base: '6', sm: '8' }}
        pl={4}
        pr={6}
        mr={4}
        // px={{ base: '4', sm: '6' }}
      >
        <Stack justify="space-between" spacing="1">
          <Stack spacing={{ base: '5', sm: '6' }} shouldWrapChildren>
            
            <InputGroup>
              <InputLeftElement pointerEvents="none">
                <Icon as={FiSearch} color="muted" boxSize="5" />
              </InputLeftElement>
              <Input placeholder="Search" />
            </InputGroup>
            <Stack spacing="1" >
              <NavButton label="Home"  fontWeight="normal"/>
              <NavButton label="Dashboard" aria-current="page" fontWeight="normal" />
              <NavButton label="Tasks"  fontWeight="normal"  />
              
              <NavButton label="ddd"  fontWeight="normal"/>
            </Stack>
          </Stack>
          <Stack spacing={{ base: '5', sm: '6' }}>
            <Stack spacing="1">
              <NavButton label="Library" fontWeight="normal" />
              <NavButton label="Help"  fontWeight="normal"/>
              <NavButton label="Settings"  fontWeight="normal"/>
            </Stack>
            {/* <Box bg="bg-subtle" px="4" py="5" borderRadius="lg">
              <Stack spacing="4">
                <Stack spacing="1">
                  <Text fontSize="sm" fontWeight="medium">
                    Almost there
                  </Text>
                  <Text fontSize="sm" color="muted">
                    Fill in some more information about you and your person.
                  </Text>
                </Stack>
                <Progress value={80} size="sm" aria-label="Profile Update Progress" />
                <HStack spacing="3">
                  <Button variant="link" size="sm">
                    Dismiss
                  </Button>
                  <Button variant="link" size="sm" colorScheme="blue">
                    Update profile
                  </Button>
                </HStack>
              </Stack>
            </Box> */}
            <Divider />
            <UserProfile
              name="Asdfon"
              // image="adsf"
              title="adsf, asdf"
            />
          </Stack>
        </Stack>
      </Flex>
    </Flex>
  )  

const Navbar = () => {
    const { isOpen, onToggle, onClose } = useDisclosure()
    return (
      <Box
        width="full"
        maxW="100%"
        py="4"
        px={0}
        // px={{ base: '4', md: '8' }}
        bg="bg-surface"
        boxShadow={useColorModeValue('sm', 'sm-dark')}
       
      >
        <Flex justify="space-between">
          
          <ToggleButton isOpen={isOpen} aria-label="Open Menu" onClick={onToggle} />
          <Drawer
            isOpen={isOpen}
            placement="left"
            onClose={onClose}
            isFullHeight
            preserveScrollBarGap
            // Only disabled for showcase
            trapFocus={false}
          >
            <DrawerOverlay />
            <DrawerContent>
              <Sidebar />
            </DrawerContent>
          </Drawer>
        </Flex>
      </Box>
    )
  }  


interface NavButtonProps extends ButtonProps {
    // icon: As
    label: string
}
  
const NavButton = (props: NavButtonProps) => {
    const {  label, ...buttonProps } = props
    return (
      <Button variant="ghost" justifyContent="start" {...buttonProps}>
        <HStack spacing="3">
          {/* <Icon as={icon} boxSize="6" color="subtle" /> */}
          <Text>{label}</Text>
        </HStack>
      </Button>
    )
  }  
  
 const DashBase = () => {
    const isDesktop = useBreakpointValue({ base: false, lg: true })
    return (
      <Flex
        as="section"
        direction={{ base: 'column', lg: 'row' }}
        height="100vh"
        bg="white"
        mb="100px"
        overflowY="auto"
        minW="100%" 
        px={0}
        mx="0px"
        // minW="120em"
        // margin="auto"
      >
        {isDesktop ? <Sidebar /> : <Navbar />}
  
        <Container py="8" flex="1">
          <Stack spacing={{ base: '8', lg: '6' }}>
            <Stack
              spacing="4"
              direction={{ base: 'column', lg: 'row' }}
            //   justify="space-between"
              align={{ base: 'start', lg: 'center' }}
            >
              <Stack spacing="1">
                <Heading size={useBreakpointValue({ base: 'xs', lg: 'sm' })} fontWeight="medium">
                  Dashboard
                </Heading>
                <Text color="muted">All important metrics at a glance</Text>
              </Stack>
              <HStack spacing="3">
                <Button variant="secondary" leftIcon={<FiDownloadCloud fontSize="1.25rem" />}>
                  Download
                </Button>
                <Button variant="primary">Create</Button>
              </HStack>
            </Stack>
            {/* <Stack spacing={{ base: '5', lg: '6' }} maxW="100%">
              <SimpleGrid columns={{ base: 1, md: 3 }} gap="6">
                <Card />
                <Card />
                <Card />
              </SimpleGrid>
            </Stack> */}
            <Card minH="sm" />
          </Stack>
        </Container>
      </Flex>
    )
  }

  export default DashBase;
```

Comment: Can you provide more details about the structure of the code? Without more details I can't give you a specific answer. Generally, for two different components to use the same data (like a list of items) you'll either need to import the data into both components, or pass the data through the component tree as props.

Comment: Hi @TylerAuer - I added the dashboard. I'm trying to use the navbuttons to determine what to display in the main segment of the page shell.

Answer (score 0):

You could wrap your `NavButton` in `Link`

```
<Link href="/settings">
  <NavButton label="Home"  fontWeight="normal"/>
</Link>
```

In `pages/settings.tsx`, have a component that renders your settings page.

In `_app.tsx`, pass `Component` as a child to `Sidebar`

```
<Sidebar>
  <Component {...pageProps} />
</Sidebar>
```

In `Sidebar`, add a param for children. `Component` will be in the `children` props. Render `children` prop after the menu.

```
const Sidebar = ({ children }) => (
  ...
    </Flex>
    {children}
  </Flex>
)
```